# What is the rails reference for a custom edit action not showing in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a password_resets controller and I want to make the URL prettier for just the edit action.

This is in my routes file:

```
  get     'resetpassword/:id/edit'  => 'password_resets#edit'
```

which I've tested and it works! The hard thing is that now I don't know how to access it.

My bin/rake routes looks like this:

```
         forgotpassword GET    /forgotpassword(.:format)                   password_resets#new
                        GET    /resetpassword/:id/edit(.:format)           password_resets#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)                  password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)              password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)         password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)              password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)              password_resets#update
```

Namely, my custom URL doesn't have a prefix to it. So how do I access it in my code?

This is what I have which works in the code but doesn't use the custom url.

```
<%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your route:

```
get  'resetpassword/:id/edit'  => 'password_resets#edit', as: :reset_password_pretty
```

There is the guide for that:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html